# pass 1d array of length > 2^16 to an excel column with vb.net

Tags: vb.net

If I have a 1 dimensional array of 1 million indexes, is there a way to do a one-liner to pass the array into a sheet?

This works for arr.length < 2^16

```
wk.Range(String.Concat("a1:a", arr.Length)).Value = XlApp.Application.transpose(arr)
```

but not for arr.length = 1 million. I've done this in VBA, but it takes several lines of code and isn't very efficient.

I've also seen a one-liner done in Python, so I was wondering if Vb.net could do it.

Comment: Older versions of Excel have a row limit of 65535 (=2^16 - 1)

Comment: I"m using Excel 2007 and this is the limit. Is there not a way  of getting around this if I want to dump a 1 million index array?

Comment: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/excel-specifications-and-limits-HP010073849.aspx says that the worksheet size limit in Excel 2007 is 1,048,576 rows by 16,384 columns. I would assume that is for the .xlsx format, not the legacy .xls format.

Are you using .xlsx?

Comment: maybe I'm doing something wrong, but I always run into an error (runtime error '13', type mismatch) when i do: sheets(sheetname).columns(1).value = application.transpose(arr) with arr being a 1 dimensional array with the index greater than 2^16.